# Sublime video - Can't play video, Your browser can't play video using HTML5

Tags: html5-video

I used Sublime Video player to embed .mov, .mp4, and .mp3 files on a project I worked on a few months ago. It all used to work perfectly. I went back to this project this morning and the player mentions "Can't play video, Your browser can't play video using HTML5" and I can't play some of the videos/podcasts anymore. Some videos don't play either on my site or on "Publish video" interface provided on the Sublime video website (seems to be a MIME issue), some play in the "Publish video" interface, but not on my local machine or live environment.

Did something change recently? Why am I having this problem now?